# Play two audio files consequtively with seamless transition on iOS

Tags: avfoundation, audiotoolbox

I am in need to play audio files that are in my apps bundle (locally stored) one after the other with a seamless transition between them.

Using an AVComposition is not good for me since I only know the second audio file name after the first has started playing and so I cant append them together before hand.

I have tried to work with two AVAudioPlayers and start the second one right when the first ends, but the transition is not 100% accurate and so I am hearing a (very) small silence between the two.

I am thinking that the only way is to break the audio into bytes and play them as stream but I am stuck at this point (considering this is the direction).

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can try `AVQueuePlayer`.

When you know the second audio file name after the first has started playing, get the asset of  the second audio with

> AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:fileURL options:nil];

Then load the asset with

> [asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:[NSArray
>   arrayWithObject:tracksKey] completionHandler:

When loading completes, add new item to player queue with

> [queuePlayer insertItem:anItem afterItem:nil];

When first audio completes playing, the player will continue to play the second audio. I haven't try, but I guess there will be no pause.